# Can anyone identify what language this code is?

Tags: dotcms

I'm trying to identify what language this code is (being used in DotCMS) so i can learn to code it. Any help identifying this would be massively appreciated. Code has been desensitized.

```
#panelStart('XXX.XXX' )
  <div class="col-md-6">
    #readOnlyField('XXX', 'XXX.XXX', $XXX.XXX, {'XXX':X, 'notCurrency':true})
    #readOnlyField('XXX', 'XXX.XXX', $XXX.XXX, {'XXX':X, 'notCurrency':true})
    #readOnlyField('XXX', 'XXX.XXX', $XXX.XXX, {'XXX':X, 'notCurrency':true})
    #readOnlyField('XXX', 'XXX.XXX', $XXX.XXX, {'XXX':X, 'notCurrency':true})
  </div>
#panelEnd
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the oficial [dotCMS](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/developing-and-apis#ClientSide) documentation, they use HTML, CSS and Javascript as a programming language.

Comment: Hi, i know the CSS, HTML and JS parts but im trying to figure out what the # parts are (such as #updateForm)

Answer (score 0):

The "#" signs are used by Apache Velocity, which is the main server-side scripting language dotCMS support.

In Velocity, "#" signs identify Velocity commands, macros, or directives.

But those aren't built-in Velocity commands, and they're unlikely to be directives (which require Java code to implement), so they're probably macros.  You'll need to look in other files to see where those macros are defined.